# iOS: Instruments, allocations peaking to a flat line

Tags: ios, crash, instruments, allocation, virtual-memory

I'm trying to learn how to use instruments. I wonder is I can get some opinions or insight at to what is going on here.

Firstly, shortly after 02:00 my app crashes due to creating many high resolution views. You can see the graph peak when the views are created. I think around 20 - 30 rendered views at aprox 1000 points.

[image]

My question is this: Note how the graph peaks and flattens at the end of the track (see the red arrow), starting just before 02:00 when the views are created, does this mean that the device (an iPhone 5) has "run out of memory". I see that the allocations listed as "All Allocations" is 17.76MB. Could this be the reason for the crash? Or is it the graphics crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does this mean that the device (an iPhone 5) has "run out of memory"?

No. It is relative to peak active memory used in that run. Illustration: you would likely see the allocation amount at 1 minute "shrink" when you start creating all those views around 2 minutes.